# Postgres query not using indexes

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a table with 2000000 records. 
I have one index:

```
CREATE INDEX test
    ON public."PaymentReceipt" USING btree
    ("CompanyID" DESC NULLS LAST, created_at ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

If I run this query, it will run the index:

```
explain 
select * 
from public."PaymentReceipt" 
where "CompanyID" = '5c67762bd0949' 
order by "created_at" desc 
limit 100 offset 1600589
```

But if I run this query, it won't use the index:

```
explain 
select * 
from public."PaymentReceipt" 
where "CompanyID" = '5c67762bd0949' 
order by "created_at" desc 
limit 100 offset 1600590
```

I'm not sure what happened to the index!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain) as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). [No screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Answer (score 0):

`OFFSET` is [bad for query performance](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

The reason is that in order to skip the first 1000000 rows, the database has to find and then discard them. So the work for the database is the same as if you omit the `OFFSET` clause.

Now sequential scans of a table are cheaper than index scans, so the latter offer an advantage only if the number of rows retrieved is much smaller than with a sequential scan. At some point the query plan will “tilt” and PostgreSQL will assume that an index scan is cheaper. You have found exactly that point.

If your `random_page_cost` setting reflects your hardware correctly, PostgreSQL will estimate this correctly. In a nutshell, PostgreSQL is doing the right thing.

Comment: I am doing paging functions, are there any ways to do that with PostgreSQL and which is the most optimal way.

Comment: What is a paging function? Do you mean that you want to paginate the result set? If yes, then the link I gave you focuses on exactly that.